# ReactJS: order JSON objects stored in this.state by a certain property of the object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm doing the front end of my rails app with ReactJS. I have a table component composed of table rows, each row is populated by an object stored in the state of the table component. The objects were obtained by making an ajax call to my rails backend. When the callback returns I set the result to a property in the state called 'data'.

In the render function, I passed each object into a subcomponent called TableRow. I stored the collection of all the TableRow subcomponents in a variable and rendered them in the JSX to display all the rows.

The question is: how do I organize each row by a certain property in the object that this row represents? In this case, each row represents an 'interview' object, each interview has a interviewDate property. Let's say that I want to organize all the interviews by their date and then render them in that order, how would I do that?

One approach I tried was to try to pass all the objects into a sorting algorithm (merge sort or quick sort), make yet another another array with the objects in the right order, then use `this.setState` to reset the state with the new array. The problem is that I can't even access the properties of the objects at all. When I try to `console.log(interviewObject.interviewDate)`, I see a browser error saying interviewDate is not a function. I googled around and it seems that the browser doesn't count JSON objects as actual JavaScript objects (don't quote me on this, I could be wrong).

Another way is maybe try to sort the objects on the server side using ruby, but I really want to do this on the client side because at some point I would like to have a function where the user can click on a column of the table and have the rows re-ordered by that column, and firing off a ton of ajax requests to the server each time the user want to re-order some data that's already on the client side to the server just seems redundant, messy and error prone.

So is there a possible solution to do this on the client side? Here is my code for your reference.

```
var ContentTable = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return ({
      data:''
    })
  },
  getData: function(){
    console.log('requesting data...')
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(results) {
          this.setState({data:results})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.getData();
  },
  handleUpdate: function(){
    this.getData();
  },
  render: function() {
    var dataArray=[]

    for (var key in this.state.data){
      dataArray.push(this.state.data[key])
    }

    //define table headers and other properties to pass down to row component
    var tableHeaderArray=[]
    for (var header in dataArray[0]){
      if(header!=="id"){
          tableHeaderArray.push(header)
      }
    }
    var url=this.props.url
    var handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate
    var dataModel=this.props.model


    var tableHeaders= tableHeaderArray.map(function(header){
        return <th key={header}> {header}</th>
    })


    var tableRows= dataArray.map(function(data){
        return <TableRow url={url} model={dataModel} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} headers={tableHeaderArray} data={data} key={"interview "+data.id} />
    })
    return (
        <div className="widget-content">
          <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {tableHeaders}
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {tableRows}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just sort the array?

Comment: the array contains objects, javascript wouldn't know which property to sort the array by

Comment: Check out the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of array. It let's you specify your own compare function if you want. So, just do: `myarr.sort(function(a, b) { //logic here to decide which comes first })`

Answer (score -1):

This logic should definitely be on the front end. This is definitely not something that should be given to the backend to handle.

I don't know much about React, but in Ember we use a sortable mixin, its pretty much the same principle.

Here you go - https://github.com/danielstocks/react-sortable